# Odoo8 Qweb generated pdf document. The tablerows on the 2nd page are jammed

Tags: pdf, report, wkhtmltopdf, odoo, qweb

On the 2nd 3rd etc. page the tableheader and tablerows of quotation or invoice are jammed, when I print the document in pdf format.
This works the same (wrong) way in my own written templates too.

Brand new installed LinuxMint17 (Ubuntu clone), latest odoo8 (2015-01-29), wkhtmltox0.12.2.1

[image: Here is]

Is this a bug or a feature?
Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers! Janos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hear it means that the current Report not using the compatible version of
**Wkhtmltopdf python  library**

you need to check from version of current **Wkhtmltopdf** python library  and

if it 0.12 to lower remove and reinstall then install the latest **Wkhtmltopdf 0.12.X** version or later and print your report again.

I hope this should help you.

Comment: I've downgraded wkhtmltox to the 0.12.1 version, and  everything works well!

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug with **wkhtmltox**. I've downgraded to **wkhtmltox-0.12.1** and everything works fine.

Comment: This is not a "thank you" answer.  There isn't any other answer to thank.  This is THE answer.